# C++ conversion operator with parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

Is there any way to define a conversion operator that takes a parameter?

Here is my use case:

```
class RGBColor
{
    operator RGBAColor (const float alpha = 1.0) const noexcept;
}
```

I have conversion operators to/from HSB and RGB colors, and RGBA to RGB (by dropping the alpha), but I'm having difficulty converting from RGB to RGBA since I need to the ability to supply the alpha as a parameter (rather than always defaulting to one).

I assume that I'm going to have to fall back to something like:

```
RGBAColor ToRGBAColor (const float alpha = 1.0) const noexcept;
```

However, I would prefer to use standard C++ conversion, so I'm just wondering if there's any way to use a conversion operator that takes a parameter.

Comment: That's what constructors ar for.

Comment: A conversion operator cannot take an additional argument. How would you supply it? Your conversion function, OTOH, looks fine to me.

Comment: @IntellectualKitty As mentioned, provide a constructor like `RGBAColor(const RGBColor & rgb, float alpha = 1.0)`

Comment: @IntellectualKitty: "*I'd prefer to use a member function that takes a single parameter*" - that is exactly what `ToRGBAColor()` is, eg: `RGBColor oldColor(...); ... RGBAColor newColor = oldColor.ToRGBAColor(someAlphaValu‌​e);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to pass additional parameters to a cast operator. The syntax doesn't allow that.

As mentioned in comments and in the other answer, provide an appropriate constructor instead:

```
struct RGB {
    float r_;
    float g_;
    float b_;
};

struct RGBA : RGB {
    float alpha_;

    RGBA(const RGB& rgb) : RGB(rgb), alpha_(1.0) {}
    RGBA(const RGB& rgb, float alpha) : RGB(rgb), alpha_(alpha) {} // <<<<
    RGBA& operator=(const RGB& rgb) {
        *static_cast<RGB*>(this) = rgb;
        alpha_ = 1.0;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: @IntellectualKitty You can accept answers by clicking the big checkmark appearing at the left of it. You don't need to write your own answer to state that.

Answer (score 4):

This is literally what constructors are for.

Declare and define one.

Comment: [Fleshed out a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37040394/1413395), expecting critiques.

Comment: @IntellectualKitty: You're asking how to do something by using a feature other than that which was created to do that thing. Can a conversion operator take a parameter? Of course it can. Otherwise what would it be converting? But you're trying to force a square peg through a round hole. Why? _"I want to avoid [] littering my code with.."_ then don't litter your code. Write a constructor that is called like `RGBAColor(oldColor, someAlphaValue)`, or a member function `oldColor.changeAlpha(someAlphaValue)` that returns a new `RGBAColor` (warning: bad name; make clearer that it returns by value).